# Check elastic IP attached to an ec2 instance using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to check if the public IP address attached to an instance is Elastic or not, using boto3 ?

Is there a method that i can call and get this information ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Network Interface association has an owner field:

```
"NetworkInterfaces": [
    {
        "Status": "in-use", 
        "MacAddress": "06:68:22:33:44:c1", 
        "SourceDestCheck": true, 
        "VpcId": "vpc-1234", 
        "Description": "", 
        "Association": {
            "PublicIp": "13.54.133.222", 
            "PublicDnsName": "ec2-13-54-133-222.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com", 
            "IpOwnerId": "amazon"
        },
```

The `IpOwnerId` is either the AWS Account number (for an Elastic IP address) or `amazon` (for a temporary public IP address).

You can retrieve it with:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].NetworkInterfaces[*].Association.[PublicIp,IpOwnerId]'
```

You could similarly access this information via `boto3`.

Comment: You could similarly access this information via boto3. I think that was the actual question, which I have myself.

Comment: @jjones150 In boto3, call [`describe_instances()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances), and the same information as shown above will be returned. Just navigate the JSON to retrieve the element.